# Issue with inserting dynamically generated table into a div

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am dynamically generating rows of a table from the ajax response I am getting. The table headers are static/constant. I am finally writing this to a div on a page.

The div has both horizontal and vertical scroll. My issue is this: If say I have 100 rows I can't see the headers/table columns. I want to make it like freeze pane in excel, where you can see the headers/columns.

I tried separating the headers/columns from the rows but the issue I face is wide, i.e. the row td size doesn't match up to the headers. Here's my code (sample code):

I want to make it work in IE7 and Firefox.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <html>
     <head>
      <title> Some Page </title>
       <meta name="Author" content="">
      <meta name="Keywords" content="">
      <meta name="Description" content="">
     </head>

     <body>
      <div id="dataDiv" style="white-space:nowrap; overflow-y:scroll; height:330px;overflow: scrollbars-vertical;overflow-x:scroll; width:100%;overflow: scrollbars-horizontal;">
     </body>
    </html>


    <script>


    function ProcessResponse(ajaxResponseData) 
    {

        var dataList = ajaxResponseData.somDataList;



        if(dataList != null)
        {

            var rowData = "<table border='1'  width=1200px>";
            rowData += "<tr>"           
                + "<td colspan='6'><b>Header1</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header2</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header3</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header4</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header5</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header6</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header7</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header8</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header9</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header10</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header11</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header12</b></td>"
                + "<td colspan='4'><b>Header13</b></td>"
                +"</tr>";




            for(var i=0;i<dataList.length;i++)
            {
                var someRowData=new Object();
                someRowData = dataList[i];


                rowData+="<tr>"             
                +"<td colspan='6'>"
                +someRowData.Header1_data+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header2_data
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header3_data
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header4_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header5_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header6_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header7_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header8_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header9_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header10_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header11_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header12_data
                +"</td>" 
                +"</td><td colspan='4'>"
                +someRowData.Header13_data  
                +"</tr>";
            }
            rowData+="</table>";


            var dataDiv=document.getElementbyId("dataDiv");

            if(dataList.length == 0)
            {

                dataDiv.innerHTML="";
            }   
            else    
            {           
                dataDiv.innerHTML=rowData;
            }   

        }

    }
    </script>
```

Please help. Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is set `overflow: auto;` to the `tbody` element rather than your `div` (and keep your `th` elements in a `thead` element). This won't work (without some tweaking/hacking) in anything but Firefox though (maybe Opera as well - not sure). Check the link @smnbss provided and you should probably solve it. The biggest problem is that you have to set fixed width's to all your cells if you want it to work in all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

you have to play a little bit with css

have a look at this:

http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: @Nomad right click view the source, here is my attempt of a pure css table http://jsfiddle.net/dKEy5/

Comment: @Tom Ingram thanks but the cell are not aligned in your example with header. What if I want to have 10 headers?

Comment: @smnbss Apparently IE9 isn't a memeber of the "Big Four"

Comment: @Nomad although there's a lot going on the source code of the link provided by smnbss most of it is styling and is worth a read through as it seems to take into account different browsers. I have updated my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/dKEy5/1/embedded/result/) to use fixed size columns

Comment: @Tom Ingram, Thanks for updating it. It works in FF but in IE7 the headers disappear. I mean the effect is working fine in FF 3.6 but in IE7 if you scroll the header1 and header2 disappear.

Comment: @smnbss in IE7, the full data is not shown which it shows in FF. In IE7 shows Cell Content 1, Cell Content 2, Cell Content 3.Can you explain why?

Comment: @Nomad unfortunately I cannot (nor have the tenacity to) test browser compatibility issues. I have however been playing around with a 'tableless' table layout. I need to tidy up the js but [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dafastestfingers/eNNNp/7/) is what I have so far